# Replacing a substring

Tags: strings, text-manipulation, substitution

I've got a string like this: `aXYbXYc`, and need to replace the `XY` substring with a right arrow: `a $\to$ b $\to$ c`.

Is there any function  (also provided by external packages) to help me do that?

Comment: Like [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)? E.g., `sed 's/\([a-z]\)XY/\1 $\\to$ /g' myfile.tex`...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\def\ReplaceStr#1{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{XY}{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{XY}{$\to$}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\ReplaceStr{aXYbXYc}

\ReplaceStr{abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use minimal for examples.

Comment: What is the point in using `\IfSubStr`?

Comment: I cannot remember, so I must say it is without any sense ...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\substr[3]{%
  \setsepchar{#2}%
  \readlist\parsedinput{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\parsedinput{%
    \ifnum\xcnt=1\else#3\fi\x%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\substr{aXYbXYc}{XY}{$\to$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried to use your `\substr` twice but couldn't make it work. Can you tell me what I did wrong? For instance, I added spaces in the starting string and I'd like to remove them in addition to the usual substitution. Here the code: `\substr{\substr{a XY b XY c}{ }{}}{XY}{$\to$}` (The result I get is: `aXYbXYcc`) TIA!

Comment: @StefanoBragaglia One cannot nest invocations of `\substr`.  But in this case, one need not do so, There is an alternate invocation of `\readlist` (that is, `\readlist*`) which strips away spaces that surround the searched-for text (in this case, `XY`).  Thus, changing `\readlist` to `\readlist*` in the definition of `\substr` allows for an invocation of `\substr{a XY b XY c}{XY}{$\to$}`, which does the desired substitution and removes the spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Just to add to the conversation, I was looking for a more general solution: what if I'd like to replace spaces with `\quad`? My own solution is using `\StrSubstitute` from `xstring` but has many limitations (to say the least). The trick they use is to set a variable on the fly: `\newcommand{\subst}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{XY}{$\to$}[\tempvar]\StrSubstitute{\tempvar}{ }{\quad}}`

Comment: @StefanoBragaglia `listofitems` also can employ nested searches, which allows you to search for more than one thing at a time.  Then you would use a nested `\foreachitem` to handle each level of the nest.

Comment: `listofitems` seems to be very powerful! I'll study it in more details! Thanks for pointing out these details!