# Replacing characters in argument strings

Tags: strings

I am trying to create a LaTeX command that will allow me to insert pre-defined tables with a minimum of fuss. This will also allow me to change the overall format of tables (e.g. caption above or below) globally, without having to modify each instance.

Ideally, I am thinking something along the lines of `\includetable{label}{caption}`, where `label` corresponds to the float's label (for linking purposes), and `caption` corresponds to the caption displayed above (or below) the table. I would like to use `label` for the filename also, e.g. the table contents would be defined in `label.tex`.

The problem I have is that I use colons in my labels to distinguish tables, figures, and sections in a consistent manner. For example, a table relating to a structure's mass budget would have a label like `t:structure:mass`; in Windows, I cannot have colons in filenames, so I would like the function `\includetable` to replace colons with hyphens when calling `\input`.

The closest thing I've found on Stack Overflow is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95824/replace-a-character-with-a-string-in-latex, but I can't get this to work with colons instead of commas. Suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Do you tried the solution with the package `xstring`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/replacing-a-substring

Answer (score 21):

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\includetable}[2]{%
  \begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{#2}\label{#1}
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{:}{-}[\temp]%
  \input{\temp}
  \end{table}}
```

Some variations are possible. One can think, for example, to a key-value syntax for deciding the position of the caption and for providing a short caption.

Comment: The package is named `xstring` without the s.

Answer (score 5):

To be compiled with luaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{t-mysection-mytable.tab}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
  10 & 20 \\
  20 & 40
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}

\def\includetable#1#2{%
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \input{%
      \directlua{%
        local s, _ = string.gsub("#1",":","-")
        tex.sprint(s)}.tab}%
    \caption{#2}\label{#1}
  \end{table}}

\begin{document}

\includetable{t:mysection:mytable}{My table}

\end{document}
```