# Replacing ampersands in argument

Tags: xstring, ampersand

I am trying to define a command which takes as an argument a string containing ampersands, and replaces every ampersand by a space. Following the ideas in  [Replacing characters in argument strings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36266/replacing-characters-in-argument-strings), I defined my command as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\colvec[1]{%
    \saveexpandmode\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1}&\ [\vectorentries]%
    \restoreexpandmode[\vectorentries]^T}
```

This works great, except in `align` environments, where the ampersands get recognized as column markers and latex gets confused. How should I fix my code to work in `align` environments as well?

Here is a minimum-non-working-example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand\colvec[1]{%
    \saveexpandmode\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1}&\ [\vectorentries]%
    \restoreexpandmode[\vectorentries]^T}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x = \colvec{3 & 3}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a different token?

Comment: Because i'm using it in a 500-page book and the command shows up many many times. But maybe you're right; I should use some regular expression search and replace to change the token... I thought there might be a simple answer to my question.

Comment: At second thought -- there is: place the interior of the command between `{...}`. This should hide the `&` from `align`'s scanning mechansim.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I meant by "simple solution"! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transforming my comment into an answer: you need to hide the ampersand from `align`'s scanning mechanism.

The easiest way to do this is placing the command in braces:

```
\begin{align}
 x = {\colvec{3 & 3}}
\end{align}
```

To have a more comfortable syntax one can add the braces to the definition of `\colvec`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand\colvec[1]{%
    {\saveexpandmode\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1}&\ [\vectorentries]%
    \restoreexpandmode[\vectorentries]^T}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 x &= \colvec{3 & 3} \\
 E &= mc^2 % to show that alignment still works
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, and looking back, I regret having asked the question because the solution is embarrassingly simple. I expected that it was going to take catcodes etc. Pfew!

Answer (score 4):

Why not using a simpler strategy?

```
\newcommand{\colvec}[1]{
  {
   \setlength{\arraycolsep}{.16667em}
   [\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}]^T
  }
}
```

A different way of replacing the `&` with a space is with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colvec}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { & } { \  }
  [\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl]^T
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This doesn't even require the extra braces.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this is what I used before. The problem with it is that if you use this in a sentence, the vertical alignment does not always come out correctly. Also, if there are subscripts or superscripts, the brackets become bigger than necessary.

Comment: I changed the macro; can you show a place where the alignment is not correct? Just curious.

Comment: see my next question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55007/matrix-vertical-alignment . it's driving me crazy!