# Matrix vertical alignment in combination with double spacing

Tags: matrices

Why does the following code mess up the vertical alignment in the matrices?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

The first case is
$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{matrix}\right]$.

The second case is
$\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{matrix}\right]$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first case, the numbers are clearly too low, and the brackets are too long. This is due to the value of `baselinestretch`, which I cancel out by taking `arraystretch` = `1/baselinestretch` in the second case. But here, the numbers come out just too high, and moreover the brackets are too long.

How to deal with this?

Comment: what happens if your remove the `doublespacing` command? Also, the first case should be `$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$`. The second case is strange here and should be avoided.

Comment: @pluton: Without the doublespacing command everything looks fine. Using `bmatrix` gives exactly the same output.

Comment: and you want to keep the doublespacing option?

Comment: Yes, I need to keep double spacing

Comment: Matrices (even one row matrices) are "vertical objects", so the interline space influences their typesetting.

Comment: Actually, I found the real problem: when specifying `doublespacing`, the value `baselinestretch` is not `2.0` but `1.667`. So `1/baselinestretch` should not be `0.5` but `0.618`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrices are centred rather than aligned on the baseline of a row. You get slightly better spacing if you use bmatrix or with delarray you can align on the top row (but then you don't get the[image] spacing adjustments of the AMS version)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,delarray} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing 
\begin{document} 
The first case is $\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{matrix}\right]$.

The first case is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. bm

The first case is $\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{ccc}\rbrack 1 & 2 & 3 \end{array}$. da

The second case is
$\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{matrix}\right]$.

The second case is
$\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. bm

The second case is
$\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}\begin{array}[t]\lbrack{ccc}\rbrack 1 & 2 & 3 \end{array}$. da


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I found what was the problem: a (to me) unexpected value of `baselinestretch`, see my comment above.