# Where Is \arraystretch?

Tags: spacing, matrices

`setspace.sty` shows that `doublespacing` changes `baselinestretch`, but where is the relation between `baselinestretch` and `arraystretch`? I need the exact number of `arraystretch` to resize my `bmatrix`s. [Matrix vertical alignment in combination with double spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55007) shows `baselinestretch`=`1/arraystretch`, but where can I find this information? It seems neither `setspace.sty` nor `amsmath.sty` has the information.

Comment: (1) Where can I find the macro then? (2) What if ```doublespacing``` makes ```baselinestretch``` ```1.617```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `\setstretch` or derived command such as `\doublespacing` is issued, the normal value of `\baselineskip` is multiplied by the stated `\baselinestretch`.

When `array` or `tabular` are started, the *current* value of `\baselineskip` is multiplied by `\arraystretch`. Thus you want that `\arraystretch` is set to the reciprocal of `\baselinestretch`.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\fixstretch}{\edef\arraystretch{\fpeval{1/(\baselinestretch)}}}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

Some text that should be long enough to be broken across lines
so as to show the interline spacing. But now we show a matrix
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\]
The result is really awful. Now we try in a different way.

\fixstretch
Some text that should be long enough to be broken across lines
so as to show the interline spacing. But now we show a matrix
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\]
Now the matrix is nice. Of course, the double spaced
text remains as ugly as it can be.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may avoid the need to issue explicitly `\fixstretch` by redefining `\setstretch`.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xfp}

% fix \setstretch to also act on \arraystretch
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\setstretch}[1]{%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \edef\arraystretch{\fpeval{1/#1}}% <---- added code
  \@currsize
}
\makeatother

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

Some text that should be long enough to be broken across lines
so as to show the interline spacing. But now we show a matrix
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\]
Now the matrix is nice. Of course, the double spaced
text remains as ugly as it can be.

\end{document}
```

[image]