# Better \vspace{} and dashed line in array-environment

Tags: arrays, vspace

In this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{A_MEG_Blocchi}
A^{(\:\:)}\coloneqq\Tonde{\begin{array}{c|c}\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\\cline{2-2}&K\end{array}}=
\Tonde{\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}a_{11}^{(1)}&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&a_{1n}^{(1)}\\0&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots\\\vdots&\ddots&a_{k-1,k-1}^{(k-1)}&\cdots&\cdots&a_{k-1,n}^{(k-1)}\\[2mm]\cline{4-6}0&\cdots&0&a_{kk}^{(k)}&\cdots&a_{kn}^{(k)}\\[2mm]\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{$\mathop{\Scale[5]{0}}$}}&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\&&&a_{nk}^{(k)}&\cdots&a_{k+1,n}^{(k)}\\[2mm]\end{array}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have a better `\vspace` between the rows of this `array` and I'd like to add a horizzontal dash line between 4th and 5th rows (but only for three first coloumns) and why the vertical line is broken? Thank you so much.

Comment: How or where is `\Scale` defined?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Anyway, have you tried to change `\arraystretch`?

Comment: To get the extra vertical line segment, change `\multicolumn{3}{c}{...}` to `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{...}`.

Comment: @JuanCastano I don't know \arraystretch

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564125/where-is-arraystretch.

Comment: I didn't solved my problem yet, could you help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem so:

```
\begin{equation}\label{A_MEG_Blocchi}
A^{(\:\:)} \coloneqq
\Tonde{
  \begin{array}{c|c}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \cline{2-2}
    \phantom{K} & K % <-- '\phantom{K}' is new
  \end{array}}
=
\Tonde{\begingroup{
  \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
    a_{11}^{(1)}&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&a_{1n}^{(1)} \\
    0&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots \\
    \vdots&\ddots&a_{k-1,k-1}^{(k-1)}&\cdots&\cdots&a_{k-1,n}^{(k-1)} \\[1mm]
    \cline{4-6}
    0&\cdots&0&a_{kk}^{(k)} & \cdots & a_{kn}^{(k)} \\[-7.5mm] \hdotsfor[0.75]{3}\\[-2.5mm]
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\Scale[4]{$0$}}}
    &\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    &&&a_{nk}^{(k)}&\cdots&a_{k+1,n}^{(k)}
  \end{array}}\endgroup}
\end{equation}
```

Thank you Mico!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `\vspace` to increase the separation between rows in an `array`. Instead, set `\arraystretch` to a number greater than 1. In the code below, I run `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\coloneqq' macro
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} % <-- new

\begin{equation}\label{A_MEG_Blocchi}
A^{(\:\:)} \coloneqq
\Tonde{
  \begin{array}{c|c}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \cline{2-2}
    \phantom{K} & K % <-- '\phantom{K}' is new
  \end{array}}
=
\Tonde{
  \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
    a_{11}^{(1)}&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&a_{1n}^{(1)} \\
    0&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots \\
    \vdots&\ddots&a_{k-1,k-1}^{(k-1)}&\cdots&\cdots&a_{k-1,n}^{(k-1)} \\[1mm]
    \cline{4-6}
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\Scale[4]{$0$}}}
    &a_{kk}^{(k)} & \cdots & a_{kn}^{(k)} \\
    & & & \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    &&&a_{nk}^{(k)}&\cdots&a_{k+1,n}^{(k)}
  \end{array}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico. If I'd like to space only this array, how must I do? And then, the horizzontal dashed line? Thnak you again

Comment: @Puck - To limit the scope of the `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` directive to just this particular `equation` environment, place a `\begingroup` instruction right before `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` and an `\endgroup` instruction immediately after `\end{equation}`. I'm afraid I don't know what you're referring to with "the horizzontal dashed line". Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{A_MEG_Blocchi}
A^{(\:\:)} \coloneqq
\Tonde{
  \begin{tblr}{c|c}
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} & \\
    \cline{2-2}
    \phantom{K} & K % <-- '\phantom{K}' is new
  \end{tblr}}
=
\Tonde{
  \begin{tblr}{ccc|ccc}
    a_{11}^{(1)}&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&a_{1n}^{(1)} \\
    0&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots \\
    \vdots&\ddots&a_{k-1,k-1}^{(k-1)}&\cdots&\cdots&a_{k-1,n}^{(k-1)} \\
    \cline[dashed]{1-3}\cline{4-6}
    \SetCell[r=3,c=3]{c}\Scale[4]{$0$} & &
    &a_{kk}^{(k)} & \cdots & a_{kn}^{(k)} \\
    & & & \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    &&&a_{nk}^{(k)}&\cdots&a_{k+1,n}^{(k)}
  \end{tblr}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you **@LJR**, never seen this **tblr**-environment. I think that your great solution will be useful for me in order to substitute other particular **array**-environment. Thank you so much again

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do with `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,stix}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{A_MEG_Blocchi}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
A^{(\:\:)} \coloneqq
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin=3pt,columns-width=5mm]
  \\
  & K 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (3-|2) |- (2-|3) ;
\end{pNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin=3pt,xdots/line-style=dotted,xdots/shorten=1pt]
  a_{11}^{(1)}&\Cdots&&&&a_{1n}^{(1)} \\
  0&\Ddots&&&&\Vdots \\
  0&0&a_{k-1,k-1}^{(k-1)}&&\Cdots&a_{k-1,n}^{(k-1)} \\
  \Block{3-3}<\Huge>{$0$} &  &  &a_{kk}^{(k)} & \Cdots & a_{kn}^{(k)} \\
  & & & \Vdots&\Ddots&\Vdots\\
  &&&a_{nk}^{(k)}&\Cdots&a_{k+1,n}^{(k)}
\CodeAfter
  \line{2-1}{3-1}
  \line{2-1}{3-2}
  \line{3-1}{3-2}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1-|4) -- (last-|4) (4-|4) -- (4-|last) ; 
    \draw [dashed] (4-|1) -- (4-|4) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]