# Replacing substrings by linebreaks

Tags: strings, text-manipulation, xstring, substitution

I have a LaTeX document with several authors that I enter like `\author{First Author \& Second Author \& ...`. In some places in the document I want to print these authors with a linebreak behind every name, i.e. I want to replace all occurences of `\&` by `\\` (or an equivalent command).

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/replacing-a-substring) about an almost identical issue, except that no linebreak is to be inserted.
Trying `\StrSubstitute{text \& text}{ \& }{\\}` I get a whole bunch of errors and no output. The linebreak seems to break the `\StrSubstitute` macro.

Is there a way to prevent this from failing? If not, what other approach will work?

Comment: Typically `\author` stores its argument in `\@author`, which is cleared after a call to `\maketitle`. What do you use in order to access this via `\theauthor`? Please answer this in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Check `\noexpandargs` in the documentation of `xstring`

Comment: @Werner: Right, I forgot about that. I use the `titling` package which provides `\theauthor`. I replaced it by plain text in my question.

David's suggestion works like a charm, so I don't think, a MWE is necessary anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX is a macro expansion language: do not use string substitution: simply redefine the macro

```
{\renewcommand\&{\\} \theauthor}
```

will evaluate `\theauthor` in a local context where `\&` means linebreak.

Answer (score 9):

David's answer is precious, efficient and nice for the problem at hand. However, it doesn't deal with the error you get.

The package `xstring` has three modes of operations:

1. `\fullexpandarg`
2. `\expandarg`
3. `\noexpandarg`

and the first is the default. They are described in section 3.1.1 of the manual, together with the list of what arguments of the provided commands are subject to this expansion. In the case of `\StrSubstitute`, *all* arguments but the trailing optional one are influenced by the mode of operation. So your

```
\StrSubstitute{\theauthor}{\&}{\\}
```

will do full expansion of `\theauthor`, `\&` and `\\`. You may be were lucky enough that `\theauthor` survives full expansion (it does if authors' names don't contain accented letters); `\&` is not dangerous, because it's internally defined with `\chardef`, which makes it unexpandable; `\\` will definitely not survive full expansion, because its operations require doing definitions.

Now you know that `\fullexpandarg` is not good, but `\noexpandarg` isn't either, because you *want* to expand `\theauthor` once or `\&` wouldn't be found: you need the list of authors' names, not the macro containing them. What can you do? There are several possibilities.

#### Use `\expandarg`

```
\saveexpandmode % remember what's the current mode of operations
\expandarg % operation mode where only one step of expansion is performed
\StrSubstitute{\theauthor}{\&}{\noexpand\\}
\restoreexpandmode % restore the previous mode of operations
```

#### Use `\noexpandarg`

```
\saveexpandmode % remember what's the current mode of operations
\noexpandarg % operation mode where only one step of expansion is performed
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\theauthor}{\&}{\\}%
\restoreexpandmode % restore the previous mode of operations
```

Choose the method you like better. You can also say `\expandarg` or `\noexpandarg` in the preamble after `\usepackage{xstring}`, changing mode when you need a different one.

Changing the mode will also respect grouping, so

```
\begingroup
\expandarg % operation mode where only one step of expansion is performed
\StrSubstitute{\theauthor}{\&}{\noexpand\\}%
\endgroup
```

would restore the previous mode. If you just need printing the changed token list, then this may be sufficient. Of course `\renewcommand{\&}{\\}` is more efficient, but in other cases you might need these tricks.

---

A different strategy is with `l3regex`:

```
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\printauthors{O{\\}}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl \theauthor
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{&} } { \u{l_tmpa_tl} } \l_tmpb_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then `\printauthors` would do the same substitution as you want; with `\printauthors[<something else>]` you can change `\&` into whatever you like.

Comment: Wow, great answer! However, there seems to be a missing backtick in your last paragraph even swallowing some text.

Comment: @schtreber Thanks for noticing; it should be fixed, now.

Comment: Update: `l3regex` should not be loaded with recent versions of `expl3`.