# Carry out substring replacement on variable's contents

Tags: strings, xstring

Say I have a variable that contains some non-plain text, for instance `\def\var{Caro \textit{et al.}}`, and I want to make a substring substitution of `Caro` for `\underline{Caro}`. If I try to follow the recipe from [Replacing a substring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/replacing-a-substring), this will fail:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xstring}
\def\ReplaceStr#1{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{Caro}{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{Caro}{\underline{Caro}}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\def\var{Caro \textit{et al.}}

\ReplaceStr{\var}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the formatting from the variable definition, i.e. `\def\var{Caro et al.}`, then it works:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xstring}
\def\ReplaceStr#1{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{Caro}{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{Caro}{\underline{Caro}}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\def\var{Caro et al.}

\ReplaceStr{\var}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, in my actual case I have no way to directly modify the formatting that `\var` comes with since it's generated through a series of commands. How can I either:

- Remove all formatting from `\var` (i.e. make it "plain text") before I do the substring replacement
- Make the string replacement act correctly on formatted text

For the curious, my actual `\var` comes from a biblatex call: `\def\var{\citename{somebibitem}{author}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful with expansion; by default `xstring` performs full expansion and `\textit` doesn't survive it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\replacecaro[1]{%
  \begingroup\expandarg
  \IfSubStr{#1}{Caro}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{Caro}{\underline{Caro}}}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\var}{Caro \textit{et al.}}

\replacecaro{\var}

\end{document}
```

[image]

***Don't*** use `\def` in LaTeX unless you know precisely why you need it.

Comment: Thanks, this does work for my simplification of the problem, but unfortunately does not work for my actual problem where the definition of `\var` is actually `\newcommand{\var}{\citename{caro_2015}{author}}` and `caro_2015` is a bibitem where `M. A. Caro` is the outcome of `\citename{caro_2015}{author}`. I will accept your answer but help on this more complicated scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: @Miguel Much more information is needed for the full scenario. In a new question with all the details. But I think you can already find something about the problem on the site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=highlight+author

Comment: Thanks again. I have seen most of those answers already but I don't like the most common solution of directly editing the bibfile. I will keep researching a bit and post another question if I don't manage what I want.

Comment: @Miguel The solutions within `biblatex` seem more effective.

Comment: I finally gave up and ended up writing a small bash `sed` command to generate a temporary bib file from my master bib file with the correct formatting...