# Replace a substring

Tags: strings, substitution

This is actually a follow-up question to [Replacing a substring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/replacing-a-substring) from 6 years ago.

I want to replace a substring in a long string. With `\ReplaceStr` from the *xstring*-package this works perfectly fine.
However, if I want to *nest* multiple of such functions, I get the error `Use of \@xs@StrSubstitute@@ doesn't match its definition. \ReplaceStrB{\ReplaceStr{aXYbXYc}}`

Any remarks and workarounds are warmly appreciated. I know how to substitute strings outside of LaTeX. However, in this particular case I need a LaTeX-only solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrX}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{Y}}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrB}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{b}{B}}

\begin{document}
\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}                    % produces aYbYc
\ReplaceStrB{aXbXc}                    % produces aXBXc
\ReplaceStrB{\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}}      % should produce aYBYc
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 1: The simple solution**

Simply add `\noexpandarg\exploregroups` as suggested by Manuel.
This worked for my problem. In other cases, also check out Manuel's macro-solution or cfr's 13regex-solution.

**EDIT 2: A related question**

The following successfully produces `aXBXc`

```
\ReplaceStrB{aXbXc}
```

However this does not work.

```
\def\tempvar{aXbXc}
\ReplaceStrB{\tempvar}
```

Any idea, how to safe `\tempvar` as a string?

Comment: Welcome! Please don't use `minimal` for examples.

Comment: Any suggestions for my *EDIT*? I think, it's a trivial question, but I could not figure it out...

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do it this way at all, so not really ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313585/21930), you can do this with those macros. (I will use the second version because the namespace is already `freplace` rather than `hmenke`, but the first one works as well.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { c }

\NewDocumentCommand \setfreplace { +m +m }
 {
  \freplace_set:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \freplace { +m +m +m }
 {
  \freplace:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\quark_new:N \q_freplace
\quark_new:N \q_freplacestop
\cs_new:Npn \freplace:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \exp_not:f { \use:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } ):n } { #3 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \freplace_set:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } ):n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxi:nw } { } ##1 { \exp_not:N \q_freplace }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxi:nw } ##1 ##2 ##
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_nobraces:nfn }
     { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_do:n } { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_nobraces:nnn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxii:nn } { ##1 ##2 }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_nobraces:nnn } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxii:nn } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_freplace } { ##2 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_addbraces:nfw }
       { ##1 } { \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } ):n } { ##2 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_addbraces:nnw } ##1 ##2
   {
    \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxi:nw } { ##1 { ##2 } }
   }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_addbraces:nnw } { nf }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_do:n } ##1
   {
    \exp_not:N \tl_if_empty:nTF { ##1 }
     { \exp_stop_f: }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxiii:nww }
       { } ##1 \exp_not:n { #1 \q_freplace \q_freplacestop }
     }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxiii:nww } ##1 ##2 #1 ##3 \q_freplacestop
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_if_eq:nnTF { \exp_not:N \q_freplace } { ##3 }
     { \exp_stop_f: ##1 ##2 }
     {
      \exp_not:c { freplace_( \tl_to_str:n { #1 } )_( \tl_to_str:n { #2 } )_auxiii:nww }
       { ##1 ##2 \exp_not:n { #2 } } ##3 \exp_not:N \q_freplacestop
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \freplace:nnn { nnV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_replace_nested:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \freplace_set:nn { #2 } { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \freplace:nnV { #2 } { #3 } #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setfreplace{X}{Y} % these two lines are mandatory, for each \freplace you use
\setfreplace{b}{B} % in the document, you have to first declare it with \setfreplace

\newcommand\ReplaceStrX[1]{\freplace{X}{Y}{#1}}
\newcommand\ReplaceStrB[1]{\freplace{b}{B}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc} produces aYbYc\par
\ReplaceStrB{aXbXc} produces aXBXc\par
\ReplaceStrB{\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}} should produce aYBYc\par

\end{document}
```

This does not only work in nested braces, but it's indeed an expandable solution. This version uses the syntax `\freplace{search}{replace}{token list where you search}`, and requires you to issue a single `\setfreplace{search}{replace}` for each different search & replace you use (to create the needed macros).

The other version in the answer I linked uses the syntax `\freplace{name}{token list to replace}` where what you have to write before is `\setfreplace{name}{search}{replace}`, i.e., give the pair a symbolic name. If you prefer that syntax, copy the code from the first part of the answer.

---

In any case, this code seems to compile

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xstring}

\noexpandarg\exploregroups
\newcommand\ReplaceStrX[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{Y}}
\newcommand\ReplaceStrB[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{b}{B}}

\begin{document}

\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}\ produces aYbYc\par
\ReplaceStrB{aXbXc}\ produces aXBXc\par
\ReplaceStrB{\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}}\ should produce aYBYc\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, if you actually want to *expand* the argument inside the command before doing the “first” replacement, that can be done easily, e.g., `\freplace{search}{replace}{\freplace{X}{ch}{searX}}` should produce `replace` rather than `search` (this means that `X` in converted to `ch` *before* `search` is converted to `replace`, rather than the other way around).

Comment: Thanks Manuel and @cfr for your detailed answers. For my purpose they all work the same, so I prefer the very short answer of Manuel, which uses `\noexpandarg\exploreroups`.
Please tell me, which one I should mark as the accepted answer, especially since `13regex` is still experimental.

Comment: Still, I don't understand the order in which nested functions are executed. I tried with all three solutions presented here, and they all execute the outer function _before_ the inner function... 
So `\freplace{search}{replace}{\freplace{X}{ch}{searX}}` in fact returns `searX` when I test it...

Or if I replace w with 1 and ww with 2 I get:
`\ReplaceStrW{\ReplaceStrWW{w-ww-www}} \par % returns 1-11-111` and 
`\ReplaceStrWW{\ReplaceStrW{w-ww-www}} \par % returns 1-2-21`

Comment: So you actually want to execute before the inner function? In that case it's easy to tweak. Just add `\ExplSyntaxOn \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \freplace { +m +m +m }
 {
  \freplace:nnf { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \freplace:nnn { nnf } \ExplSyntaxOff`. If that works for you I can add that to the answer.

Comment: I just found out, that `\ReplaceStrW\ReplaceStrWW{w-ww-www}` (omitting the curly brackets) does the trick as well.
Comming from phython I am just very much used to the inner-then-outer syntax. To me it is counter-intuitive, that `\ReplaceStrW{\ReplaceStrWW{w-ww-www}}` produces something different than 
`\ReplaceStrW\ReplaceStrWW{w-ww-www}`.

If you are willing to edit your answer, maybe move the solution with `\noexpandarg\exploregroups` to the beginning, since this is the part, I accept most. For my purpose there's no need for macros and many lines. What could such reasons be?

Answer (score 5):

A version using the new `l3regex` package (which is currently experimental, I believe).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3regex,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_lab_string_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \lab_replace_me:nnn
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lab_string_tl { #3 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \l_lab_string_tl
  \l_lab_string_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ReplaceStrX { +m }
{
  \group_begin:
  \lab_replace_me:nnn { X } { Y } { #1 }
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ReplaceStrB { +m }
{
  \group_begin:
  \lab_replace_me:nnn { b } { B } { #1 }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}                    % produces aYbYc
\ReplaceStrB{aXbXc}                    % produces aXBXc
\ReplaceStrB{\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}}      % should produce aYBYc
\end{document}
```

[image: string replacements]

Comment: `l3regex` has been around a while: it's 'experimental' largely as we have to agree on a final form for inclusion in `l3kernel`

Comment: @JosephWright I just thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 2):

The `StrSubstitute` command actually has a final optional argument to deal with precisely this. This argument allows you to supply a name to give to the result of the substitution. The result will then be stored in a command with this name, which can be passed to the next `StrSubstitute` you wish to carry out (or other similar `xstring` commands).

For example, your double substitution can be carried out like this:

`\StrSubstitute{aXbXc}{X}{Y}[\afterXtoY]\StrSubstitute{\afterXtoY}{b}{B}`

If you want to create new commands that perform each substitution, and don't mind making a third command to perform first the X to Y and then the b to B substitution rather than having just two commands, then this would work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrX}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{Y}}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrB}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{b}{B}}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrBX}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{Y}[\afterReplaceStrX]\StrSubstitute{\afterReplaceStrX}{b}{B}}

\begin{document}

\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}                    % produces aYbYc
\ReplaceStrB{aXbXc}                    % produces aXBXc
\ReplaceStrBX{aXbXc}                   % produces aYBYc

\end{document}
```

If you want only two commands, this works (although you do now need to type an extra `{}` when using the `\ReplaceStrX` command by itself):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrX}[2]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{Y}[#2]}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrB}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{b}{B}}

\begin{document}
\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}{}                    % produces aYbYc
\ReplaceStrB{aXbXc}                    % produces aXBXc

\ReplaceStrX{aXbXc}{\afterReplaceStrX}\ReplaceStrB{\afterReplaceStrX} % produces aYBYc

\end{document}
```

Of course, you could do the same for `\ReplaceStrB` to get a pair of commands usable together in either order (which in your example gives the same result but with the different substitution commands in this example does not):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrX}[2]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{bd}[#2]}
\newcommand{\ReplaceStrB}[2]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{b}{Xb}[#2]}
%\newcommand{\ReplaceStrBX}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{Y}[\afterReplaceStrX]\StrSubstitute{\afterReplaceStrX}{b}{B}}

\begin{document}

\ReplaceStrX{aXbc}{}                    % produces abdbc
\ReplaceStrB{aXbc}{}                    % produces aXXbc

\ReplaceStrX{aXbc}{\afterReplaceStrX}\ReplaceStrB{\afterReplaceStrX}{} % produces aXbdXbc 
\ReplaceStrB{aXbc}{\afterReplaceStrB}\ReplaceStrX{\afterReplaceStrB}{} % produces abdbdbc

\end{document}
```